# Can I verify my own transaction?

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, unconfirmed-transactions

I'm waiting since 16/12/2020 and i still waiting in the Mempool. Exists a way how can i verify my own transaction without a Bitcoin miner? Yes, i paid a low fee.

Here you can see my transaction:
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/cc32cd350dde5a9141e8180c63fb1aff4245d212d11c8249c58789a93acce4a3

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there exist two possibilities to release your stuck transactions using [Fee Bumping](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Fee_bumping):

> This page gives exact instructions on how to increase the fee on a transaction that is currently stuck in order to make it unstuck. This is always done by creating a new transaction that will either spend the coins sent by the stuck transaction (called [child-pays-for-parent](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_fees#Feerates_for_dependent_transactions_.28child-pays-for-parent.29), or CPFP) or replace the stuck transaction (called [replace-by-fee](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Replace_by_fee), or RBF).

Edit: I recommend consulting [Johoe's Mempool Statistics](https://jochen-hoenicke.de/queue/#0,24h) next time before you broadcast a new transaction.